# Why my SQL query done with read_sql is returning an empty dataframe

Tags: sql, pandas, read-csv

I am using python to query a database with sql with the sqlite3 package.
I am sure the query is well formulated in terms of conditions, but still the read_csv method is returning an empty df, like the conditions are not satisfied. I know this to be false, since this exact same query is giving good results on a different script.

```
    con = sqlite3.connect('cloud_database')
    c = con.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OGS_DB (OGS, SAT, OGS_Start, OGS_End)')
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cloud_DB (SkyStart, SkyEnd)')
    con.commit()

    OGS_DB.to_sql('OGS_DB', con, if_exists='replace', index=False)
    Cloud_DB.to_sql('Cloud_DB', con, if_exists='replace', index=False)

    OGS_DB_CLOUD = pd.read_sql('''
              SELECT *
              FROM OGS_DB AS B
              INNER JOIN Cloud_DB AS R
              WHERE (B.OGS_START >= R.SKYSTART AND B.OGS_START<=R.SKYEND)
              OR
              (B.OGS_END >= R.SKYSTART AND B.OGS_END <=R.SKYEND)
              OR
              ((B.OGS_START >= R.SKYSTART AND B.OGS_START <= R.SKYEND) AND (B.OGS_END >= R.SKYSTART AND B.OGS_END <= R.SKYEND))
              OR
              (B.OGS_START <= R.SKYSTART AND B.OGS_END >= R.SKYEND)
              ''', con)
```

Do you have any suggestions?